# Trying to group by foreign key to get only one row each time that's the most recent effectiveDate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wanting to create a view from the following SQL that 'returns all the fields but groups on PremiseProviderId to only shows the row with the newest (most recent) effective date. I'm having a brain freeze today, many thanks...

```
SELECT  RateableValue, FreeDescriptor, saaRef, VATRate, Discount, 
        PremiseProviderId, EffectiveDate,
        TransactionDateTime, TransactionDateTimeEnd, EnteredBy
FROM      PremiseProviderVersions
WHERE     (TransactionDateTimeEnd IS NULL)
ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: This table has foreign key PremiseProviderId, this value repeats. This table is a version table. So I want to create a view that will only show the rows from PremiseProviderVersions table that have the newest effectiveDate. Like a MAX(effectiveDate) and grouping on PremiseProviderId so it becomes unique in results but the trick being to still see all the other data for that row

Comment: SELECT     PremiseProviderId,Max(effectiveDate)
FROM         dbo.PremiseProviderVersions
WHERE     (TransactionDateTimeEnd IS NULL)
GROUP BY PremiseProviderId

Comment: But I need to see the other fields, ahh I think I can add a select before this and do a where IN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the row number by `PremiseProviderId` and then filter only ones that have this number equal to 1:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  RateableValue, FreeDescriptor, saaRef, VATRate, Discount, 
            PremiseProviderId, EffectiveDate,
            TransactionDateTime, TransactionDateTimeEnd, EnteredBy,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PremiseProviderId ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC) as rowNumber
    FROM      PremiseProviderVersions
    WHERE     (TransactionDateTimeEnd IS NULL)
) data
WHERE data.rowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, wondering if thats faster than a solution with select where in then a group by